# JAVA: Why am i getting a "reached end of file while parsing" error in my code?

Tags: java

Ive proofread this multiple times and I am still getting the same error. I've rewritten it as well to no avail. I've narrowed the problem down to this method. Please help!

Code:

```
public static int toss(int[] tosses) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tosses.length; i++) {
        tosses[i] = rollDie1();
    }
  for(int i = 0; i < tosses.length - 1; i++) {
    if(tosses[i] == tosses[i+1]) {
        run++;
        i++;
        while(tosses[i] == tosses[i+1]) {
        run++;
        if(run > maxRun) {   
            maxRun++;
            index = i - run;
            }
            i++;
        }
            run = 0;
        }

    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Fixing your indentation might help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code of your file.

Comment: *I've narrowed the problem down to this method.* Posted code does not reproduce the described error. Please post enough code to reproduce the error. And specify the version of Java. Commands you are running. Platform you are using. And version of same. And indenting your code is a good idea. When copying here you can highlight the code and press ctrl-k (here, in your browser; after you paste) so that it preserves whatever indentation you are actually using (if that helps)

Answer (score 1):

The "reached end of file when parsing" error occurs when you're missing a curly brace in your program. I recommend rereading your code and matching up each curly brace with its partner. Formatting better may help you catch these errors faster in the future. If you're using an IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse, here are some shortcuts that will auto-format your code for you.

IntelliJ:

1. on Windows do Ctrl + Alt + L.
2. on Linux do Ctrl + Windows Key + Alt + L.
3. on Mac do CMD + Alt + L.

Eclipse:

- Ctrl + A and then Ctrl + Shift + F